# How to ensure the security of admin password stored in database for synchronization with LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I have an application that needs to sync periodically to my directory service (OpenLDAP or AD).

To do so, it is necessary to *bind* an *admin account* with a **DN** and **password**, to access users on LDAP.

As far as I understand, there is the possibility of using *anonymous*, however for security reasons, its use is not recommended.

Since this periodic synchronization is done *automatically by a routine* (hourly), I need to store in addition to the account DN, also admin password in the application database.

However, passwords are usually sent to be authenticated in plaintext against 
directory service (within a secure SSL / TLS connection) and the directory service itself that finds its password stored in plaintext or some hash (md5, sha-1, etc.)

How to ensure the security of *admin password stored* in database for synchronization with LDAP? Or, is there a best practice to implement a sync periodic using LDAP?

Applications examples that require password (admin) to read LDAP.

- Moodle
  (https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/LDAP_authentication#Bind_settings)
- Sugar CRM  (https://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Password_Management/Configuring_LDAP_Authentication_Using_Active_Directory/#Prerequisites)

But it does not clear how the *password* is stored.

Comment: What is your application written in? There will probably be a way to encrypt the password in your configuration, but it depends what you're using.

Comment: **Dart**. It has libraries on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages?q=crypt) that implement (DES, TRIPLEDES, AES, ...) crypto two-way, where it is used a _private key_ to encrypt and decrypt. But it is not recommended to use these algorithms to store passwords, because if someone finds the private key, they will be able to discover all passwords. So it is usually used hash, but in this use case (ldap) we need the plaintext password. I look for another approach to keeping the password secure without encryp/decrypt or even a way to protect the private key used in the encryption algorithm.

Comment: Do you really even need an "admin account"? Are you using it to make any changes? In Active Directory at least, any account can read from LDAP. It doesn't need any special permissions. If that's the case, there are hardly any consequences to the password being found.

Comment: No and I really would not want to have an "admin account". I only need to read and authenticate users. I am using _OpenLDAP_ and it allows reading users without a bind (anonymous). However, I checked for information that _Active Directory_ (maybe older version!) disabled by default _anonymous_ reading, and then would be necessary to have an "admin account" to bind with it to read the users. Does this proceed for Active Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that anonymous bind is disabled by default in Active Directory. However, if you are just reading, you don't need an "admin" account. You need *any* account. The account does not need to have any special permissions. You just need something that can authenticate to the domain.

But if you're going to be authenticating users, then you will need to get the user's password, and you can just use the user's credentials to read from LDAP. That would be true for both AD and OpenLDAP.

Comment: Just to make sure I get it right: Even with _anonymous_ permission _disabled_ can I read users in ldap without any bind?

Comment: Yes. If anonymous bind is disabled, you have to authenticate with a user account to be able to read from it, but *any* user account will allow you to read.

Comment: Yes, when any account (admin or others) is authenticated I know it can read. But, being more specific:

_connect to ldap (ip, port) -> authenticate (dn, password) -> search users_

It works fine. But, with _anonymous permission disabled_, would this be possible (_read users list without authentication, just connecting_)?

_connect to ldap (ip, port) -> search users_

Comment: If anonymous bind is disabled, you need to authenticate before you search.

Comment: It's clear now, thanks! The summary of everything:
1. Do not store passwords for later bind; 2. Anonymous disabled needs authentication from any user before searching can be done; 3. With anonymous enabled I can read; and, 4. Therefore, a periodic routine to read ldap only works if I have anonymous enabled, since I should not have a password (even encrypted) stored to bind.

Comment: 1. is a choice. You could still save a password if you need to, but you may be able to avoid it if it works for you.